# Cleaning up text in UTF-8

Tags: python, validation, utf-8, data-cleaning

I have an interface where users can enter human-readable names in **one line of text** for different types of entities, mostly referring to business-related tasks, activities and operations. This includes numbers as well.

We want this interface to support multiple human languages, but at the same time we would like to avoid entries that could break things later, specifically **formatting, new line characters, tabs, and combinations of characters or control codes that do not print.**

I am new to the topic of localization, but are there any well-known subsets of `utf-8` characters, or set of practices for validating multi-language (utf-8) text? From a practical stand point, I am mostly interested in solutions in Python, but am definitely open to general solutions in other languages. What should someone doing this keep an eye for?

Comment: *"are there any good subsets of utf-8 character [...] for validating multi-language text"* - validate against what? A set of arbitrary criteria? Can you rephrase the question to be less vague? The only concrete constraints I get from your question is "new line characters, tabs, and combinations of characters or control codes that do not print".

Comment: Also: localization is the process of you, the developer, writing the application in a way that it considers the user's locale when displaying things like currency, weights, lengths etc. Possibly also translating message strings in your application (i18n). Dealing with multilingual *user input* isn't really related to localization.

Comment: Thanks @LukasGraf I updated the OP based on your comments. As for the criteria: we still don't know exactly what combinations of characters we want to avoid, but we want to take preventive measures. I certainly know that `\n` could cause problems and that we don't need non-printable text, but I wonder if there are other things we should watch out for.

Comment: Uhm, you edited the formatting, but it's no more specific than before. What do you want to do with those strings afterwards? Use them as some sort of identifiers, or why do you worry about something breaking? "preventive measures" against what?

Comment: Thanks @LukasGraf. I dropped the tag for localization and renamed the question. The text has to be human readable and understandable, but it should not contain new lines, tabs, escape characters, (Unix) control codes, formatting tags, or anything that does not print or that is meaningless for human interpretation. I think that's it, but part of the question is to precisely identify good practices when cleaning up text from UTF-8.

Comment: First thing: don't confuse UTF-8 with Unicode. UTF-8 is an *encoding* of Unicode, and the only thing you should be using it for is I/O - everything inside your program should be Unicode.

Comment: Still - there is no such thing as generally "cleaning up" a Unicode string. It depends *entirely* on what you want to do with it. There is no silver bullet or best practices. Why should newlines be a problem? Humans can read line breaks perfectly fine. Unless you have a particular application in mind where these strings are going the be used, this question simply can't be answered.

Comment: I agree with @LukasGraf, there's a lot more to this question than you realize. What happens if you have a perfectly valid character but the font you're using doesn't support it? Did you know about [homoglyphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph#Unicode_homoglyphs)? How about [combining marks](http://www.unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html)?